# Optimizing the number of XML-like tags where only the innermost tag is respected

Tags: algorithms, strings

Given a string of characters (say `a`, `b`, ...) I want to wrap those characters by tags `<a>...</a>`, `<b>...</b>`, and so on, so that for each character the innermost tag wrapping the character should match with it.

For instance, considering a string `aabbaaca`, we may have

- `<a>aa</a><b>bb</b><a>aa</a><c>c</c><a>a</a>` (naive way)
- `<a>aa<b>bb</b>aa<c>c</c>a</a>` (optimal way)
- `<a>aa<b>bb<a>aa<c>c</c></a></b>a</a>`

to write a few. I want to minimize the number of such tags. Is there a known problem to which my problem can be reduced?